# Jeasy UI Table Column Sort

Tags: jquery, jquery-easyui

I am using a jeasy ui data grid. Html Code Is As Follows.

```
<table class="easyui-datagrid table table-striped" title="" fit="true" toolbar="#tb" id="RiskRegisterGrid"
                   data-options="url:'/RiskRegister/GetAllByCurrentProject',fitColumns:true,singleSelect:true,idField:'Id'" >
                <thead>
                    <tr>

                        <th data-options="field:'NameEn',width:200,sortable:true">@lblRiskRegister.Name</th>
                        <th data-options="field:'RCT_Name',width:200,sortable:true">Risk Catergory</th>
                        <th data-options="field:'OwnerName',width:200,sortable:true">Owner</th>
                        <th data-options="field:'PRB_Name',width:200,sortable:true">Probability</th>
                        <th data-options="field:'IMP_Name',width:200,sortable:true">Impact</th>
                        <th data-options="field:'Status',width:200,sortable:true">Status</th>
                        <th data-options="field:'CreatedBy',width:200,sortable:true">CreatedBy</th>
                        <th data-options="field:'CreatedDate',width:200" formatter="formatDate">CreatedDate</th>
                        <th data-options="field:'Id',width:200,hidden:false" formatter="editTemplate" align="center">@label.Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
```

I need to sort the all the columns which has  'sortable:true',
Unfortunately I Cannot Find Any solutions online.

Could Any One Help?

Comment: http://jeasyui.com/demo/main/index.php?plugin=DataGrid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<table class="easyui-datagrid table table-striped" title="" fit="true" toolbar="#tb" id="RiskRegisterGrid"
                   data-options="url:'/RiskRegister/GetAllByCurrentProject',fitColumns:true,singleSelect:true,idField:'Id',remoteSort:false,multiSort:true">
                <thead>
                    <tr>

                        <th data-options="field:'NameEn',width:200,sortable:true">@lblRiskRegister.Name</th>
                        <th data-options="field:'RCT_Name',width:200,sortable:true">@lblRiskRegister.RiskCatergory</th>
                        <th data-options="field:'OwnerName',width:200,sortable:true">@lblRiskRegister.Owner</th>
                        <th data-options="field:'PRB_Name',width:200,sortable:true">@lblRiskRegister.Probabilty</th>
                        <th data-options="field:'IMP_Name',width:200,sortable:true">@lblRiskRegister.Impact</th>
                        <th data-options="field:'Status',width:200,sortable:true">@lblRiskRegister.Status</th>
                        <th data-options="field:'CreatedBy',width:200,sortable:true">@lblRiskRegister.CreatedBy</th>
                        <th data-options="field:'CreatedDate',width:200" formatter="formatDate">@lblRiskRegister.CreatedDate</th>
                        <th data-options="field:'Id',width:200,hidden:false" formatter="editTemplate" align="center">@label.Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
```

You should add these two into the data options. then it works

```
remoteSort:false,multiSort:true
```